# Self referencing/constrained types without generics

Tags: typescript

I have a generic type which ensures that object values are unique. I want to define a general type without generics which does the same thing based on the value being assigned to the variable of that type.

```js
type Unique<T extends Object> = {
  [x in keyof T]: Exclude<keyof T, x> extends infer K ? K extends keyof T ? T[K] extends T[x] ? unknown : never : never : never;
} extends infer G ? G[keyof G] extends never ? T : never : never

type AreUnique = Unique<{a: string, b: number}> // {a: string, b: number}
type NotUnique = Unique<{a: string, b: string}> // never


// My Goal

const foo: UniqueObject = {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'} // No Error
const bar: UniqueObject = {a: 'foo', b: 'foo'} // Error, not assignable to never

// My failed attempt

type UniqueObject = {
  [x: string]: Object
} extends infer G ? G extends Object ? Unique<G> : never : never;

const a: UniqueObject = {
  a: 'foo',
  g: 'bar'
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwI4FcIB4AqUIA9gRwAmAzlAPIBGAVhAMbAB8UAvFAN4BQUUA2rlARwoAawggA9gDMomALoAuKAFFcdADYoiGMZJmYANFFzM8BYmSFSIAJygBpKAH4HOfIVKjx02c9m97OTdzT0x%20IJcUOBE4CQB3YSU4CAA3Wygk1PTMtJsAbk4AX2CPSzhrOwBxP0reXR9KoLNSqGTcv2wc7Nasm05OUEgoAEEbCHhkNFZYRFQMdgBDJRJgGyEAcyNKJJQAW0pbQuYAemOOJagVtbhNqG3WvYObQoHwaAA5CWAJuemftHQi2Wqw2W2B13WRygpx6uX6nBhAFkQFBKhIFup%20nQJHAVlApBIJEp-hAqLQGNMgVAAOQEiTUsE0ygLGzU4owz4qGw2CR9bG44B3FnE2ZoMn0QVsKm0wkMu5KGX09lnZTc3lGWKChYkEgIdZwBaUdTQYASWG2fpIlFSBYIY1EKALYAEXZgYD9QbQEniilS7h8XDgjaKCg0CVFEoWQTldLVFzVZpRn2Clwk9CVZhdOxZgqcfl4i7esO%20jj%20i6Khn%209YK5msopAA)

Ultimately I don't want to use generics because I simply want to clarify/assert that a certain variable is an object of unique values. No functions involved.

Comment: So you want RecordWithUniqueValues? No, not possible without a function, you have to validate the type, it's undescribeable.

Comment: @Dimava Indeed, I arrived at the same conclusion. I've chosen to just use a one line function that returns the input to do the type checking. Thank you!

Comment: @Brother58697: Since this is impossible, could you write up your own answer that says so?  I don't know if anyone else would bother to do that.

Comment: @jcalz Only because it's you who asked. What do you think of `Unique`? Could it be made more concise or clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Asserting this constraint using a concrete type isn't possible as of when this answer was written so I've resigned myself to using a short generic function that asserts on the parameter type and returns it.

```js
//Borrowing @Dimava's type name
type RecordWithUniqueValues<T extends object> = {
  [x in keyof T]: Exclude<keyof T, x> extends infer K ? K extends keyof T ? T[K] extends T[x] ? unknown : never : never : never;
} extends infer G ? G[keyof G] extends never ? T : never : never

function hasUniqueValues<T extends object>(obj: T extends RecordWithUniqueValues<T> ? T : never) { return obj }

const uniquePrimitives = hasUniqueValues({ a: 'foo', b: 'bar' } as const) // No error
const uniqueObjects = hasUniqueValues({ a: { a: 'foo' }, b: { b: 'bar' } }) // No error

const dupePrimitives = hasUniqueValues({ a: 'foo', b: 'foo' } as const) // Error - Not assignable to type never
const dupeObjects = hasUniqueValues({ a: { a: 'foo' }, b: { a: 'foo' } } as const) // Error - ...
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTBCHsCdPB3BLAdgcwAQAEAi8C2BDANzwHIBnVAFwE8AHAU1UTxzoChr7UAlOgYygAmAdXgUAFgFVE8AI4BXOgDU8AGwWkAPABVUdAB4U6iAeXAAjAFZ8KAPlQBeVAG9WqVAG09qJKgDWdKnAAM1QtAF0ALlQAUT1eNQE6DX9AkK0AGlQ9O31DY3IkILpIVABpVAB%20Mt0DIxM-AODQytD3UrCavPqtTw6quURfRDhEVCjEOgJiscZJ6fG5yABuVgBfTrqCxCKSgHEW3fcUpt2O3M3ZqZKqnQWrmYmr1lYggd4KeHBRsTxSKVkFMo1HRNDpzvlUOYrO8bAAKKFRMG1CE8fiQYSiSTSeRKVTqbR2G4PRYASmcqEgdAockgoyhqFWz34iFIFFQAwBdAACpBcKJ4FNyI4fn9sYC8SDYU5UHgosQguBwMRMmY5WY8JBiAyZeRmayySBUAA5cC6aBQVh6tkcnEAeUs1iFqBF-xxQPUUplUWlstQ8sVWtWKu9qFVfvVmu1qwNwGNpuKMEgTK%20rNQAjk9B5fI%20goczt%20rvFwNInt9-qVwb9CqV2t%20qCtMZi5pKAFo42zfqR4MgmGYVAwKKaOAxHsVLSm2en6PboRQnS6xbji6WQ2Xq4HKz65euozr6xPG9Fm6g2wA6c9AA)